# How to get SharedPreferences in KoinComponent?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences in SettingsFragment:

```
val myPrefs = activity?.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
val testEnvEnabled = myPrefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.saved_test_env_key), false)
```

This is working just fine.

Then I need to ready those preferences in **object Api : KoinComponent {**

I cannot get there context or activity.

Is there some another way to get information from shared preferences?

For me it's important just to save one information, if test env. is on or off.

I'm saving that information in SettingsFragment over switch.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Like this;

```
class Api : KoinComponent {
    private val sharedPreferences by inject<SharedPreferences> {
        parametersOf("myPref")
    }

    fun test() {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Test", 1).commit()
    }

    fun get(): Int {
        return sharedPreferences.getInt("Test", -1)
    }
}

val sharedPreferences = module {
    factory { key ->
        androidContext().getSharedPreferences(key.get<String>(0), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
    factory {
        Api()
    }
}

class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App)
            modules(sharedPreferences)
        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You did specify key of preferences in App but not in Api. How to call "myPrefs" in Api?

Comment: I edited for you.

Comment: key.get() is throwing error Type missmatch

Comment: Which version of the koin are you using?

Comment: Kotlin compiler version is 1.6

Comment: not kotlin, koin version. I tested with the version below.
def koin_version= "3.1.5"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241747/discussion-between-iwizard-and-enciyo).